# How to set up separate relay for sendmail outgoing mail to foreign domains

Tags: email-server, freebsd, sendmail

I have FreeBSD 10.1 and sendmail 8.14.9.
Assume my host is "myhost.mydomain.com" and I want:

1. All mail destined for hosts in "mydomain.com" to go to "mail.mydomain.com" while appearing to originate from "myhost.mydomain.com", and
2. All other outgoing mail to go to "extmail.mydomain.com" while appearing to originate from "myhost.mydomain.com".

Can I modify sendmail.mc (or sendmail.cf) to accomplish this?

Currently all outgoing mail is successfully going to "mail.mydomain.com" as I described in (1) above, and in my sendmail.mc there is (among other things) :

```
    MASQUERADE_AS(`mydomain.com')dnl
    MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(`mydomain.com')dnl
    define(`SMART_HOST', `mail.mydomain.com')
    define(`MAIL_HUB', `mail.mydomain.com')

    FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
    FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
    FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may want to use the Feature "mailertable"

https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/mailertables.html

Comment: This does not have any way to specify "all others" you must put in explicit domain names.

Comment: define extmail.mydomain.com as your smarthost and add a special rule to mailertable for mydomain.com to your mailertable